# What rights should I put on directory so web site users can upload photos?

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I want users to upload photos to these folders (with a PHP script)

```
upload/big
upload/thumb
```

I guess putting '777' is risky (they could upload some PHP files etc..)

What is the rights I should put on the upload folder ?

Comment: well. make sure the folder they upload to is outside of the web root, and the user the webserver is running as will need write access to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders should just have their default chmod of 755. The "trick" is to set the ownership of the folders to the user that your PHP script is running under (usually `www-data` or `apache`). If you're unsure, run this simple script:

```
<?php
echo `whoami`;
```

Then, chown the folders to this user/group, for example:

```
chown -R www-data upload/
```

That will make sure that www-data will be the owner of the upload folder and it can do as it pleases inside that folder (because the owner has full permissions).

Comment: beware that if upload is under the webroot, and not protected by some other fashion, than users will be able to upload and run arbitrary content.